# Creating RTP packets

Tags: java, video-streaming, rtp, jmf, xuggler

I'm working on a project relates Real-Time multimedia Streaming where the video is divided into rtp packets and sent to the client . In the client the rtp packets are extracted and are reassembled into a video and played using Xuggler, codec using is MPEG-4.

But i'm not getting how to create a rtp packet.
Can anyone please tell me the procedure of this. 
I'm using `JMF 2.1.1`.

```
Operating System : Windows 8 64 bit  
Language used : java
```

Comment: Packetizing depends on the codec, doesn't it? What are you using? MJPEG? H.264? ...

Comment: Haven't done it myself. I just know that it depends on the codec. So, if someone wants to help, he should know what codec you are using. If you add that info to your question, you should have better chances finding someone who can actually answer that.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple RFCs for every RTP packet you want to transmit. Here is the one for MPEG4 over RTP][1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3640)

It appears that JMF supports RTP streaming, but I don't think it supports MPEG4 out of the box. You will probably need to write a header parser and writer. There is also session negociation which you have to take into account, such as RTSP or SIP.